# Two consecutive &nbsp; are treated as on

Tags: html

The character below adds a space to my html. However when I put 2 side by side they act like their is just one. Is there a solution to this? Thanks

```
&nbsp;
```

Comment: CSS usually is a good solution to this.

Comment: Can you post an example of this happening? Two &nbsp;s are supposed to act like there are two. And they usually do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `whitespace:pre` CSS property can be used to preserve whitespace:

Alternative, using a HTML entity:

Space `&nbsp;`
Space `&ensp;`
Space `&emsp;`